# Weka: doing bagging from the command line

Tags: command-line, weka

I can train a model using Bagging from the command line like this --

```
java -Xmx512m -cp $CLASSPATH weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging -P 100 -S 1 -num-slots 1 -I 10 \
    -split-percentage 66 \
    -t $traindata \
    -d $model \
    -W weka.classifiers.trees.REPTree -- -M 2 -V 0.001 -N 3 -S 1 -L -1 -I 0.0 \
    > $out
```

But I can't reuse the same model to do prediction from the command line. I guess the command should be something like --

```
java -Xmx512m -cp $CLASSPATH weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging \   
    -l $model \
    -T $testdata \
    -W weka.classifiers.trees.REPTree \    
    -p 0 \
    > $wkresult
```

But it does not work, any idea?

**EDIT:** However, when I am doing with a single classifier (i.e. no bagging), it works. The commands were like this --

```
java -Xmx512m -cp $CLASSPATH weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomial \
    -split-percentage 66 \
    -t $traindata \
    -d $model \
    > $out

java -Xmx512m -cp $CLASSPATH weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomial \
    -T $testdata \
    -l $model \
    -p 0 \
    > $wkresult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call a different class to evaluate the model. The command line should be something like

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH weka.classifiers.Evaluation weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging \
   -T $testdata -l $model
```

You may need to specify some of the additional options you gave when training the classifier. Also have a look at the commandline options for the evaluation class. More information [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+classifier+evaluation+output+manually).

Comment: well, but when I am doing the same thing with a single classifier (i.e. no bagging, evaluation) it works. Please refer to the edit.